# How do you log something to the console without going to a new line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, console

How do you log something to the console without going to a new line in JavaScript?

Comment: console.log(param1,param2,param3);

Comment: Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Every `console.log` call will result in the argument being logged on a new line. I think your only option is to *batch* everything you want to be on a single line together (either in a single string or in separate arguments), then call `console.log` just once with that line, eg:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let lineToLog = '';
for (const char of arr) {
  lineToLog += char;
}
console.log(lineToLog);
```